# Page with custom theme returns 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I've created a page in wordpress, and assigned it a custom template. the page is a child of another page. its slug is **portfolio**, so my custom theme page is **page-portfolio.php**. It consists of header and footer and a bunch of html in between. The problem is when I view the page it returns 404 Not Found Error. my permalink is set to show only post name. but when I set it to default, it shows the page. How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could be an issue with .htaccess. Try turning off permalinks, and see if you can view the page. Then try enabling permalinks again.

Comment: @pmandell, exactly when it is set to default permalink it shows but otherwise says 404. how to fix it?

Comment: Do your other pages work with permalinks turned on?

Comment: Home page yes, but others no.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with .htaccess. Are you getting a warning the .htaccess is not writeable?

Also, make sure that 'portfolio' is not already being used as a slug for a custom post type or taxonomy.

Comment: Its fixed, rewrite module was not enabled. sorry guys. my mistake